# Autodock 4 automation script

Tags: shell, bioinformatics, docking

I am trying to perform docking using Autodock4, and I have a specific task in mind. I've downloaded a ligand library, and I need a script that will automatically dock each ligand from this library sequentially. With Autodock Vina, this is possible, and the relevant script is provided below:

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in ligand_*.pdbqt; do
    b=`basename $f .pdbqt`
    echo Processing ligand $b
    mkdir -p $b
    vina --config conf.txt --ligand $f --out ${b}/out.pdbqt --log ${b}/log.txt
done
```

However, given the numerous parameters in Autodock4 and the multiple file extensions generated during the docking process, I've found it challenging to write a similar script for Autodock4. Is it possible to automate the docking process I described using Autodock4? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I expected to be able to sequentially dock each ligand from the library without manual intervention. Is it possible for me to perform this process with Autodock4 by preparing the protein appropriately and using a similar script? Because when we do a regular docking with parameters like grid and docking, it generates specific files for the protein and ligand. Is there an alternative method?

Comment: *"However, due to the complexity and the multiple parameters involved in Autodock4,"* (this is included 2x in your posting (and other duplicates) ) . ... Well ... please edit your question to show examples of these options/constraints. BUT be warned, I read your question now as a "please write the code for me" question, which will likely be vote-closed. ALSO include your best attempt to solve your problem. You can use `case $var in opt1) do opt 1 ;; opt2 ) do opt2 ;; * ) unrecognized ;; esac` , `if/then/elif/else/fi` constructs limit the action of your script.    .......

Comment: Read [mcve] and also the section  "How to turn a bad script into a good question" in the [bash info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). Good luck.